# Why does this confuse the F# compiler's type inference?

Tags: f#, closures, type-inference

No problem here:

```
module Seq =
    let private rnd = Random Environment.TickCount

    let random =
        fun (items : 'T seq) ->
            let count = Seq.length items
            items |> Seq.nth (rnd.Next count)
```

The signature of `Seq.random` is `items:seq<'T> -> 'T`.  All good.

Yes, I know that I could just `let random items = [...]`, that is not the point.

The point is that `items` is suddenly constrained to be type `seq<obj>` when I do this:

```
module Seq =
    let random =
        let rnd = Random Environment.TickCount
        fun (items : 'T seq) ->
            let count = Seq.length items
            items |> Seq.nth (rnd.Next count)
```

... i.e. I add the `Random` object as a closure.  If I hover over `random`, Intellisense shows me that the signature has become `items:seq<obj> -> obj`.

Interestingly, if I select the code and hit `[Alt]+[Enter]` to execute it in F# Interactive, the signature shows as `seq<'a> -> 'a`.  WTH??

So, what's going on, here?  Why the confusion and inconsistency in type inference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the so-called [Value Restriction](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction). Cutting a long story short, syntactical values cannot be generic, because it might break things when mutations occur, and the compiler cannot always reliably prove immutability. (note that, even though `random` is a function semantically, it is still a value *syntactically*, and that's what matters)

But *sometimes* the compiler can prove immutability. This is why your first example works: when the right side of a `let` is a straight up lambda expression, the compiler can tell with certainty that it is immutable, and so it lets this pass.

Another example would be `let x = []` - here the compiler can see that the nil list `[]` is immutable. On the other hand, `let x = List.append [] []` won't work, because the compiler can't prove immutability in that case.

This "relaxation" of value restriction is done in F# on a case-by-case basis. F# compiler only goes as far as to handle a few special cases: literals, lambda expressions, etc., but it doesn't have a full-fledged mechanism for proving immutability in general. This is why, once you step outside of those special cases, you're not allowed to have generic values.

You can technically defeat this by adding explicit type arguments. Logically, this tells the compiler "Yes, I know it's a generic value, and that's what I meant for it to be".

```
let random<'t> : seq<'t> -> 't =
    let rnd = Random Environment.TickCount
    fun items ->
        let count = Seq.length items
        items |> Seq.nth (rnd.Next count)

let x = random [1;2;3]
```

But this will still not do what you want, because behind the scenes, such definition will be compiled to a parameterless generic method, and every time you reference such "value", the method will be called and return you a new function - with a brand new `rnd` baked in for every call. In other words, the above code will be equivalent to this:

```
let random() =
    let rnd = Random Environment.TickCount
    fun items ->
        let count = Seq.length items
        items |> Seq.nth (rnd.Next count)

let x = random() [1;2;3]
```

Comment: Very interesting. I wasn't aware of the generic let binding turned into a parameterless function. Does the same apply to `Unchecked.defaultOf<_>` and similar core library functions (that don't look like one)?

Comment: Yes. `Seq.empty` is another example.